# Fortrabbit deployment error with github

Tags: laravel, github, deployment, composer-php, fortrabbit

I'm trying to deploy a small app on fortrabbit but when I look in the console here is the error I have :

```
Pushing to user@repository.git
remote: Step1: Updating repository        
remote:  -> OK        
remote:          
remote: Step2: Deploying (strategy: no delete, excludes: no)        
remote:  -> OK        
remote:          
remote: Step3: Composer Hook        
remote:  -> Triggering install - get a coffee        
remote:    -> Installing way/form [dev-master 25d0667]        
remote:    -> Installing way/form [dev-master 25d0667]        
remote:  ! Composer threw 'RuntimeException'        
remote:  !     Failed to execute git clone --no-checkout 'git@github.com:JeffreyWay/Laravel-FormField.git' '/var/www/web/application/htdocs/vendor/way/form' && cd '/var/www/web/application/htdocs/vendor/way/form' && git remote add composer 'git@github.com:JeffreyWay/Laravel-FormField.git' && git fetch composer          
remote:  !   ~~~FAIL~~~        
remote: Step4: Executing post-deploy script        
remote:  ~ PHP Warning:  require(/var/www/web/application/htdocs/bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/web/application/htdocs/bootstrap/autoload.php on line 17        
remote:  ~ PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/var/www/web/application/htdocs/bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/opt/php/5.4/share') in /var/www/web/application/htdocs/bootstrap/autoload.php on line 17        
remote:  ~         
remote: !! FAIL !!        
remote: !! Script exited with error state        
remote: !! FAIL !!        
remote: > All Done <        
To git@git1.eu1.frbit.com:repository.git
 = [up to date]      production -> production
   2e5a195..4c9ddcc  master -> master
updating local tracking ref 'refs/remotes/production/master'
```

Do you guys have any idea why I have the github error ? 
Thanks a lot for your help.

Thoma

Comment: Try not to create a composer trigger. It seems there is something wrong with laravel form package

Comment: Hey, If I don't trigger composer then I still have the error on step 4 because composer has not loaded all requirements :s

Comment: Try to ssh in and fux it there

Comment: We had the same idea :) Just answered there :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok found it,

I've connect with SSH to fortrabbit and try to do a composer install there. 
This allowed me to add my github credentials and to clone the missing vendors :

```
13:23:51 user@fortrabbit:~/htdocs$ composer install
Warning: This development build of composer is over 30 days old. It is recommended to update it by running "/usr/bin/composer self-update" to get the latest version.
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev)
  - Installing way/form (dev-master 25d0667)
    Downloading: connection...    Failed to download way/form from dist: The "https://api.github.com/repos/JeffreyWay/Laravel-FormField/zipball/25d06676a75f05db7cc10399e72ce13c922047ae" file could not be downloaded (HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found)
    Now trying to download from source
  - Installing way/form (dev-master 25d0667)
    Cloning 25d06676a75f05db7cc10399e72ce13c922047ae
The authenticity of host 'github.com (192.30.252.131)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is {fingerprint}.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? y
Please type 'yes' or 'no': yes
Cloning failed using an ssh key for authentication, enter your GitHub credentials to access private repos
The credentials will be swapped for an OAuth token stored in /var/www/web/dir/.composer/auth.json, your password will not be stored
To revoke access to this token you can visit https://github.com/settings/applications
Username: myusername
Password:
Token successfully created

  - Installing guzzle/guzzle (v3.9.2)
    Downloading: 100%

  - Installing way/generators (2.6.1)
    Downloading: 100%

Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
Generating optimized class loader
Compiling common classes
Compiling views
```